# Firestore: Subcollections vs Root-level collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a quiz game, where players have to answer questions of different categories (sports, music, .....). Right now, I have two different ideas how to store these categories /questions in Firestore:

1. Creating a new **Root-level collection** for each category. Every document in this collection would define a question of that category. Stcuture would look like this:

   - **user_collection**

     - user_1_document
     - user_2_document
     - user_X_document
   - **music_questions_collection**

     - music_questions_1_document
     - music_questions_2_document
     - music_questions_X_document
   - **sports_questions_collection**

     - sports_questions_1_document
     - sports_questions_2_document
     - sports_questions_X_document
2. Creating ONE Root-level collection and create a document inside this collection for each category, where each document contains a subcollection of questions:

- **user_collection**

  - user_1_document
  - user_2_document
  - user_X_document
- **category_collection**

  - music_document

    - music_question_subcollection

      - music_question_document_1
      - music_question_document_2
      - music_question_document_3
  - sports_document

    - sports_question_subcollection

      - sports_question_document_1
      - sports_question_document_2
      - sports_question_document_3

I have already read [about some advantages and limitations of subcollections and root-collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), but have not found enough information regarding read-costs and speed for this specific use case. Can anyone give me some information about drawbacks and advantages of the two listed approaches.

Comment: There is a third option. Create one collection for all quiz questions and make fields like `questionLevel` `category` `questionNumber`. And just query them by fields: `query(collection(db, 'quizes'), where('category', '==', 'Sport'), where('quizLevel', '>=', '5'))`

Comment: @Mises the problem I have with this approach is, that you first have to retrieve ALL questions from a specfic category (where('category', '==', 'Sport') and then retrieve a single question, which is not really cost efficient, because the category collection will contain a lot of documents(questions).

Comment: In my opinion, you are not cost-efficient. Read about persistence. You can always download once documents and read them from browser cache. And if you make a separate collection for each category, you still have to query them all!

Comment: Oh, and you are not able in Firestore to get more than 100 documents at once. And to get the certain number of documents you're using `limit(5)` function in query, and you're getting just 5 documents. Read about how to make paginated requests to Firestore.

Comment: @Mises So let's say I have a collection called "Sports" with 10 000 documents in it. I also put an ID on these documents (1 ... 10 000). In my cloud functions, I would just create a random number between 1 and 10 000, and then query over sports collection with the condition: where('ID',  '==', random_Number), which will result in only one document read.

Comment: @Mises okay you are right, limit(x) would do the job and prevent read inefficiency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246708/discussion-between-mises-and-clyon97).

Comment: @Mises You mention that "you are not able in Firestore to get more than 100 documents at once". AFAIK there is not such a limit. Can you point out the reference for this limit?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Good to know. I don't have a clue why I was sure there is a limit to 100 documents. There is just maximum API request size 10 MiB, and it is about writes not reads.

Answer (score 3):

> I have not found enough information regarding read-costs and speed for
> this specific use case. Can anyone give me some information about
> the drawbacks and advantages of the two listed approaches?

In terms of "read-costs and speed", the two approaches are equivalent: using a root collection or a sub-collection is exactly the same.

As a matter of fact, **from a technical perspective**, a root collection and one of its sub-collections **are not at all related to each other**. They just share a part of their path but nothing else.

So, since you store **the same documents** in either a root collection or a sub-collection (i.e. same number of docs in each category collection and same field structure for these docs), there is no difference.

Comment: Okay I thought so; thank you very much!!!